# Mock the method of a Python class and return a dynamic value

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can Python's [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module be used to mock a method that uses a member of the same class?

```
class NameHelper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_id = 0

    def next_id(self):
        self.local_id += 1
        return str(self.local_id)
```

Note, I'm [patch.start and patch.stop](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#start-and-stop) to do patching in the `setUp` method:

```
class TestSomeClient(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        patcher = patch('helpers.name_helper.NameHelper')
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        self.mock_name_helper = patcher.start()

        # The actual mocked values
        self.mock_name_helper.return_value.local_id = 0
        self.mock_name_helper.return_value.next_id.return_value = 'mock-name'
```

Clearly, **mock-name** is not a sensible mock return value. The return value should use the `local_id` member of `NameHelper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why the question was down-voted with no comments. The answer is, IMO, not clear.

The Python documentation for [patch.start and patch.stop](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#start-and-stop), provides the following example for patching in setUp:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         self.patcher1 = patch('package.module.Class1')
         self.MockClass1 = self.patcher1.start()

     def tearDown(self):
         self.patcher1.stop()

MyTest('test_something').run()
```

However, when patching entire class, this is misleading. The following is more helpful:

```
class MockClass1():
    pass

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher1 = patch('package.module.Class1')
        self.MockClass1 = self.patcher1.start()
        self.MockClass1.return_value = MockClass1()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher1.stop()
```

Note, the additional line:

```
self.MockClass1.return_value = MockClass1()
```

The `return_value` should be a new instance of the class `MockClass1`. Applied to my example:

```
class MockNameHelper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_id = 0

    def next_id(self):
        self.local_id += 1
        return str(self.local_id)

class TestSomeClient(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        patcher = patch('helpers.name_helper.NameHelper')
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        self.MockNameHelper = patcher.start()
        self.MockNameHelper.return_value = MockNameHelper()
```